# connecting cisco Wireless controller and access point

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I'm fairly new to cisco wireless networking, and I'm trying to connect am AIRCAP 3602i access point to a 2504 wireless controller.

I've started off by configuring the wireless controller with a management IP of 192.168.2.1/24. This devices is not connected to anything else (not even an uplink to an internet connection).

I've then connected the AP to the wireless controller and then connected to the AP via a console cable, however I keep getting the errors below:

```
> Cisco IOS Software, C3600 Software (AP3G2-K9W8-M), Version 15.2(2)JB2,
> RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1) Technical Support:
> http://www.cisco.com/techsupport Copyright (c) 1986-2013 by Cisco
> Systems, Inc. Compiled Mon 29-Jul-13 11:27 by prod_rel_team
> *Mar  1 00:00:26.379: %SNMP-5-COLDSTART: SNMP agent on host APf872.eae8.67ea is undergoing a cold start
> *Mar  1 00:00:26.399: %CDP_PD-4-POWER_OK: Full power - HIGH_POWER inline power source
> *Mar  1 00:00:26.435: %LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface Dot11Radio0, changed state to reset
> *Mar  1 00:00:27.007: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet0, changed state to down
> *Mar  1 00:00:27.431: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface BVI1, changed state to up
> *Mar  1 00:00:27.435: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Dot11Radio0, changed state to down
> *Mar  1 00:00:27.499: %DOT11-6-FREQ_SCAN: Interface Dot11Radio0, Scanning frequencies for 9 seconds
> *Mar  1 00:00:27.511: %LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface Dot11Radio1, changed state to reset
> *Mar  1 00:00:28.511: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Dot11Radio1, changed state to down
> *Mar  1 00:00:29.855: %SOAP_FIPS-2-SELF_TEST_HW_SUCCESS: HW crypto FIPS self test passed
> *Mar  1 00:00:29.855: DPAA Initialization Complete
> *Mar  1 00:00:29.855: %SYS-3-HARIKARI: Process DPAA INIT top-level routine exited
> 
> *Mar  1 00:00:35.443: %CAPWAP-3-ERRORLOG: Could Not resolve CISCO-CAPWAP-CONTROLLER
> *Mar  1 00:00:35.443: %LWAPP-3-CLIENTERRORLOG: LWAPP LED Init: incorrect led state 255
> *Mar  1 00:00:35.467: %LINK-6-UPDOWN: Interface Dot11Radio0, changed state to uplwapp_crypto_init: MIC Present and Parsed Successfully
> 
> *Mar  1 00:00:35.599: %SSH-5-ENABLED: SSH 2.0 has been enabled
> *Mar  1 00:00:35.599: %LINK-6-UPDOWN: Interface Dot11Radio1, changed state to up
> *Mar  1 00:00:36.503: %LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface Dot11Radio1, changed state to reset
> *Mar  1 00:00:37.495: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Dot11Radio0, changed state to up
> *Mar  1 00:00:37.523: %LINK-6-UPDOWN: Interface Dot11Radio1, changed state to up
> *Mar  1 00:00:37.531: %LINK-6-UPDOWN: Interface Dot11Radio0, changed state to down
> *Mar  1 00:00:37.539: %LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface Dot11Radio0, changed state to reset
> *Mar  1 00:00:38.523: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Dot11Radio1, changed state to up
> *Mar  1 00:00:38.531: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Dot11Radio0, changed state to down
> *Mar  1 00:00:38.559: %LINK-6-UPDOWN: Interface Dot11Radio0, changed state to up
> *Mar  1 00:00:39.559: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Dot11Radio0, changed state to up%Default route without gateway, if not
> a point-to-point interface, may impact performance
> *Mar  1 00:00:55.295: Logging LWAPP message to 255.255.255.255.
> 
> *Mar  1 00:00:57.283: %LINK-6-UPDOWN: Interface BVI1, changed state to down
> *Mar  1 00:00:58.283: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface BVI1, changed state to down
```

At a later stage the errors above stop and errors similar to the one below appear:

```
Not sending discovery request AP does not have an Ip !!
```

I've found no indication on how to reset this device to factory reset.
When I connect the AP to the wireless controller it's not detected by the controller.

Can someone guide me on how to connect the AP to the Wireless controller or how to reset it to factory defaults ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi the issue is the AP cant find/see the controller.

"Could Not resolve CISCO-CAPWAP-CONTROLLER"

Most likely the cause is that the DHCP pool your using is missing option 43 = IP. this tells the AP what the WLC IP address is.

I.E

```
ip dhcp pool VLAN30
import all 
network 10.0.30.0 255.255.255.252
default-router 10.0.30.1
option 60 ascii "Cisco AP c1140"  
option 43 hex 0a00.6304 // points to 10.0.99.4 WLC
lease 0 4
```